# MinGW bison does not recognize api purity and parse-param directives

Tags: mingw, bison

I am trying to compile my parser using MinGW and MSYS2 on windows, however bison does throws errors on these lines

```
%define api.pure full
%parse-param {ast_token *last_token} {finfo *fsrc}
```

I suspect that the version of bison provided by MinGW is outdated, if so, how do I fix it?

**P.S.**
This is the output of bison --version

```
bison (GNU Bison) 2.4.2
Written by Robert Corbett and Richard Stallman.
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the output of `bison --version` so we know which version you actually have?
Which version of MSYS2 do you use?

Comment: 2.4.2 is 10 years old, you really should update.

Comment: @ssbssa is there a way to update MinGW provided bison? I don't have much experience with MinGW and windows